# Does any closed subset in a Banach space have (at least one) point that has a minimum norm?

Tags: banach-spaces

Does any closed subset in a Banach space have (at least one) point that has a minimum norm?

I think this statement is obviously true, but how do I prove its correctness?

Answer (score 1):

The previous version of my answer was wrong. The following example was suggested by [commenter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16627/commenter)(see the comments).
 The answer to this question is no. Consider the subset $$E=\left\{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)e_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subseteq \ell_2$$
where $e_n=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots) \in \ell_2$. 
$E$ is closed subset of $\ell_2, \ \inf\left\{\|x\|:x\in E\right\}=1$ and $\|x\|>1, \forall x \in E.$

Comment: Try to apply your hint to the closed subset $$
\left\{(1+1/n)e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subseteq \ell_2
$$ where $(e_n)$ is the standard orthonormal basis.

Comment: Thanks for fixing your answer. By the way: a refinement of your original hint *does work* if you assume $E$ to be closed and *convex* and the Banach space is *[uniformly convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space)*, for example $L^p(\mu)$ spaces for $1 \lt \mu \lt \infty$. Maybe the Hilbert space version of this result is what you had in mind.